# ckeditor table dialog text box not working when used in jquery ui dialog

Tags: css, ckeditor, jquery-ui-dialog, ckeditor4.x

Hi i am using `ckEditor` in inside `JQuery UI Dialog` my jquery ui dialog loading code is like

```
$("#my-div").dialog({
                    height : 700,
                    width: 500,
                    modal : true,
                    closeOnEscape: false
                });
```

When i click on `table` or `image` icon in ckeditor then it opens another dialog , below picture is sample example when i click on `table` icon, now the problem is that when table dialog is opened then every text box and drop down in that dialog become disable and i am unable to modify any `rows` or `columns` value. And when i modify the `modal` property to `false` then its working, i think there is some z-index issue , but at this time i am unable to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I Think that you need to remove all

> tabindex=-1

from

> jquery

UI dialog

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.